# Angular 7 Observable number does not update view

Tags: angular, observable

I have a problem, I don't know why the value variable is not updated in my view when using it in an observable, thanks for the help:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-observables',
  templateUrl: './observables.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./observables.component.css']
})
export class ObservablesComponent implements OnInit {
    observable: Observable<number>;
    value: number = 0;
    observer: Observer<number>;
  constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.value = 10;
        this.observable = new Observable((observer: Observer<number>) => {
            this.observer = observer;
        });
        this.observable
            .subscribe(this.handleData, this.handleError, this.handleComplete);
        this.observer.next(12);
        this.observer.next(15);
        //this.observer.complete();
        this.observer.next(16);
    }

    handleData(data) {
        this.value = data;
        console.log('Here are the usable data', data);
    }

    handleComplete() {
        console.log('Complete');
    }

    handleError(error) {
        console.log('error:', error)
        return Observable.throw(error);
    }
}
```

And this is my view:

```
{{ value }}
```

here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qmdjji)

Comment: Added stackblitz sample, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the code loses `this` (it is reassigned). You can fix this by using arrow functions.

```
this.observable.subscribe((data) => this.handleData(data), (error) => this.handleError(error), () => this.handleComplete());
```

Assigning the member to an arrow function instead of declaring them as essentially functions also solves the issue.

```
handleData = (data) => {
    this.value = data;
    console.log('Here are the usable data', data);
}

handleComplete = () => {
    console.log('Complete');
}

handleError = (error) => {
    console.log('error:', error)
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Comment: `this.handleData.bind(this)` is also an option.

Comment: No problem @Alex, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `observer`, you just need to have a `subject` so you can `next` and `complete` the `subject` and `subscribe` to your `observable` as usual by passing a call back or inline functions

```
    private subject : Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();
    observable$: Observable<number> = this.subject.asObservable();
    value: number = 0;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.value = 10;
        this.observable$
            .subscribe(this.handleData, this.handleError, this.handleComplete);
        this.subject.next(12);
        this.subject.next(15);
        //this.subject.complete();
        this.subject.next(16);
    }
```